# What do "have", "get" and "got" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

In my language *have* has exactly two different meanings. First is *possess*. In the following sentences I can replace *have* with *posses*,

I **have** a pen = I **possess** a pen
I **have** a car = I **possess** a car
I **have** this book = I **possess** this book

the second meaning is *forced to do* or 
*must do*. In simple language *have* means, that I have no other choice, I must do this. In the following sentences I can replace *have* with *forced*.

I **have** to go now = I am **forced** to go now 
I **have** to kill him = I am **forced** to kill him

I guess that in English *have* is not equivalent to *forced to*. Actually it seems that *have* in the above written two sentences means that I *posses* that job.

I have to go = I possess a job, and the job is to go
I have to kill him = I possess a job, and the job is to kill him

I also do not understand why sometimes in English *got* is used with *have*, e.g.

I have got to go now.
I have got this car.

What does *got* mean in: "I got to go" or "I get to go". Is get=got=have? As I understand *get* means *possess*.

Answer (score 2):

*Have* can be an auxillary verb, but *get* cannot.

---

*To have {noun}* means to possess something.  The "something" can be a physical object, a physical or mental state, or an outcome.

*To have {infinitive}* means to be required to do something.  It can mean "being forced to" in the sense of that there will be negative consequences if you don't do it.  It does not necessarily mean you were held at gunpoint and coerced into doing something.

*To have {past participle}* is an expression of a perfect tense (past, present or future depending on whether it's *had*, *have/has*, or *will have*).  *Have* used this way does not mean anything in and of itself, it's an auxillary verb and cannot really be substituted with another verb.

---

---

*To get {noun}* means to acquire something.  The "something" can be a physical object, a physical or mental state, or an outcome.  *I worked today and got $200; Today I got sick.  Today I got my bills paid off.*  It may also be used in place where *have* can be used when the subject is emphasizing that he/she is bringing resources to an event - i.e. acquiring resources for the event.  *This is a nice party.  I got a case of beer.*

*To get {infinitive}* means to be allowed to do something.  *I get to go to the park*.

*To get {past participle}* means to do something to become a certain state.  *I got cleaned up.*  *She was unlucky and got screwed.*

---

So, I hope that clears up any confusion you had about the meanings of *have* and *got*.

Now, with the above in mind:

> I have got this car.

*Gotten* is the proper past participle of *get* and is what should be said here, but the above is common (so common that I can't remember the last time I heard *I've gotten this car*.)

So *I have got(ten) this car* means *I have acquired this car*.  It's *to get* expressed in the present perfect tense.  Of course, if the person saying this is talking among a group of friends, he/she telling them basically the equivalent of *I have acquired this car for us*, even though it would also make sense to say *I have this car*.

This:

> I have got to go now.

is breaking the rules, but not uncommon, at least in my location.  *I gotta go* is a way to write the quickly-spoken form of this (but isn't a real word).  Avoid using it in a situation where you are expected to appear/sound educated or in writing.

Consider *to have got {infinitive}* to be a phrase of it's own, and this means the same as *to have {infinitive}* but stronger.  Also don't get it confused with the past tense of *to get {infinitive}* above.

And, as [this](http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/grammar-have-to-have-got-to/) says, in American English, *have got to* is ONLY used in the simple present tense.

Comment: *Gotten* does not exist in BrE outside the fossilised phrase *ill-gotten gains*.

Answer (score 1):

In English, to have = 'to possess',  to have to *VERB* = 'must _VERB', as in your language.

But there is a difference between 'I have got to go' and 'I get to go'.

I have got to go = I (really) must go (expressing obligation, i.e. your "forced").

I get to go = I have the opportunity|chance|freedom to go. I can choose to go.

**"Hurray! We get to go on the ark!" exclaimed the giraffe.**

Comment: As opposed to **"Hurry! We've got to go on the ark!" exclaimed the giraffe".** :D

Comment: Nice one ............. :-)

Answer (score 1):

*Have* and *get* are closely related. The root sense of *have* is, as you say, “possess”, which is a *stative* meaning: it expresses a state rather than an event. *Get* is the corresponding *eventive* verb: its root sense is “obtain”, enter into the state of possession.

But both words have a very wide range of meanings and uses beyond these core senses. To begin with, the “possession” signified by *have* is a very loose notion (as is the notion expressed by ‘genitives’ with *-‘s* or *of*): to say I *have* a disease or an idea or a job signifies connections between these things and me which are very remote from ownership; and to *get* these things has the same loose significance.

Moreover, *have* and *get* have idiomatic and grammaticalized uses in which the notions of possessing and obtaining play no role at all. *Have*, for instance, enters into these idioms and constructions:

> experiential *have* ... *I had a great time.* [*have* = “undergo, experience”]
>
> causative *have*:
>       passive ... *I had my car repaired.* [*have* = “cause (to be)*]
>       medio-passive ... *I had myself admitted to hospital* [*have* = “cause (to be)*]
>       active ... *I had Bob fix my car.* [*have* = “induce (to)”]
>
> resultative *have* ... *Now I have my kids in college I'm available.* [*have* = “occupy a state (of)”]
>
> perfect *have* ... *I have seen the elephant.* [*have* = “occupy a state arising from”)]
>
> modal *have*:
>      deontic ... *I have to see the doctor.* [*have to* =“must”]
>      epistemic ... *That has to be a mistake.* [*have to* =“must”]

*Get* has recently (over the past 150 years or so) acquired an even wider range of uses. In many cases it has invaded *have*’s domain, either substituting for *have* or ‘sharing’ the semantic space in the collocation *have got* (= ‘have’):

> causative *get*:
>       passive ... *I got my car repaired.*
>       medio-passive ... *I got myself admitted to hospital*
>       active ... *I got Bob to fix my car.*
>
> resultative *(have) got* ... *Now I've got my kids in college I'm available.*
>
> modal *(have) got to*:
>      deontic ... *I have got to see the doctor.* *You gotta have heart*
>      epistemic ... *That's got to be a mistake.* *You gotta be kidding me.*

But *get* has also squatted on the territory of other verbs, like *be* and *start* and *take*:

> passive *get* ... *Did that letter get mailed?*  [*get* = “be”]
>   medio-passive *get* ... *He got himself shot*
>
> inchoative *get* ... *He got to thinking* [*get* = “start”]
>
> locative *get* [ = “take, betake, convey”]
>      intransitive ... *Get back to Jersey, you bum*
>      transitive ... *Get him to the hospital*
>      reflexive ... *Get yourself on home*
>
> opportune *get* ... *I got to see the elephant* [*get* = “be permitted, be fortunate enough to”]

In most cases, *get* has a more active or eventive sense than *have*. But this is not always the case; compare

> He was shot.
>   He got himself shot.
>   He had himself shot.

The version with *get* implies that ‘he’ somehow contributed to the shooting—perhaps he provoked it. But it does not imply, as the version with *had* does, that ‘he’ actively sought the shooting.

Comment: As a native speaker do you see _have_ as two different words? In "I _have_ to go", `have=must`, and in "I _have_ a disease", `have=possess`. There are many words in my native language which have multiple meanings, depending upon the context.

Comment: @user31782 In every respect except the orthographic they are different words: different pronunciations, different meanings, different functions.

Comment: Does _have_ mean _to possess a job_? E.g. _I have to go = I possess a job, and the job is to go_ Is this meaning correct? I guess, it's not because _have=must_, a completely different meaning from _to possess_.

Comment: @user31782 No: in *have to* = 'must', *have* is completely bleached of any possessive connotation. It's now a different word, not even pronounced the same as lexical *have*.

Comment: Do you mean that _have_ has two different pronunciations?

Comment: @user31782 Yes. As a lexical verb or an auxiliary it is pronounced with /v/ or /z/: *have/has*. But in the *have to* collocation it is pronounced with /f/ or /s/: you will sometimes see it written *hafta/hasta*, when the author wants to mark the colloquial register.

Comment: @user31782, Stoney There's another important difference. When auxiliary *HAVE* is not stressed, or is not the last word in the sentence then it is usually pronounced /əv/. This is the same way we usually pronounce the word "of". If it is the first word in an utterance we usually pronounce it /həv/ and we can't drop the /h/. When it is stressed or it is the last word in the sentence, we pronounce it like lexical verb/main verb *HAVE*: /hæv/.

Comment: @Araucaria W e l l -- cisatlantically, unstressed auxiliary *have* at the beginning of an utterance (which I think only happens with interrogatives) is mostly abbreviated to bare /v/, or dropped altogether.

Comment: @StoneyB, User, Yes, that's true here too. I should really have said "in slow careful speech" etc. You'll never go wrong with putting a full /həv/ at the beginning. If you put /əv/ you'll sound weird. /v/ is fine, but probably not good for formal speaking, (imo). But the important thing is to try not to use /hæv/ in normal auxiliary position - so that you can use emphasis when you want to, so you don't sound like you're giving it contrastive stress, and so as to put less strain on your listener.

Comment: @Araucaria And I should have made an exception for negative questions, where the /hæv/ syllable is stressed. --But I think it is only the influence of written English that leads us to think of *have* as the 'base' form of the auxiliary: nowadays I think it's really a set of clitics /(ə)v/, /(ᵻ)z/, /(ᵻ)d/, with the optional vowel expandable to /hæ/ for emphasis.