# Can GET + past participle be explained as acquisition of state?

Tags: grammar, causative-get

Verb *to get* has a prototypical meaning of acquiring something by some means. The following phrases:

- to get tired
- to get late
- to get married

share common sense of acquiring some state represented by *past participle*. Could therefore *GET + past participle* grammatical construction be explained is an acquisition of state? Is there some counter-example?

P.S. As observed in comments by @StoneyB *late* is not a *past participle*, but it's still a state. So it seems reasonable to keep this example.

Comment: *late* is not a past participle, though a participle may lie behind it 'way back in PIE. Otherwise, this is a very ingenious analysis of what's usually analyzed as a sort of 'agentive' passive. But *get* has developed a lot of auxiliary uses over the past couple centuries; see [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/47191/32)

Comment: ('Auxiliary' in a non-technical sense. *Get* has none of the auxiliary properties: it is inflected for 3sg, it doesn't invert in questions and negatives, it can't 'code', and it isn't employed for emphasis.)

Comment: The nuance is more "become" than "acquire".  "I got tired" => "I became tired".  It suggests a process over time, rather than a single event.

Comment: @Andrew - Although "I got arrested" certainly suggests a single event.  "Get + *past-participle*" is actually really tricky to define properly, I'm finding.

Comment: "get" + past participle can express a process or an action in the passive: *He got upset (process) when he got arrested (passive).*

Comment: What would you do with this construction when a reflexive pronoun is added? You could get yourself killed/in trouble/banned from the game, etc.

Comment: @KarlG That's a very interesting point, thx for mentioning. It's more aligned with protosense *to pull yourself into a state* which is more in harmony with *become* (get pulled into a new state by some force, external or internal).

Answer (score 1):

RESEARCH:

http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/auxiliaryverb.htm

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/get?s=t

http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-to%20marry.html

http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-get.html

EXPLANATION

- To get married == [auxiliary verb] + [past participle]

"Get" is used as an auxiliary verb followed by a past participle to form the passive, to get married; to get elected; to get hit by a car.   The verb "get" is used an auxiliary verb which compliments "to have become married".  The verb get is often used in compliment to express the sentiment "have become, have acquired, have caused" and will take the active "I will be married" and turn it passive "I got or will get married".

Yes, the verb "get" has a fundamental meaning or core meaning of acquisition, however as an aside, I would not apply "prototypical" as this would imply "first example".  This example is actually example [23](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/get?s=t), but that is no more nor less than number 1, there is no precedence.  There are many counter examples, see examples 5 and 6 in the dictionary.com definition of get.

> share common sense of acquiring some state represented by past
>   participle. Could therefore GET + past participle grammatical
>   construction be explained is an acquisition of state?

Yes. This is exactly the implication.  Get married is a passive acquisition of state, as is "get tired".  In this context the verb get is commonly used, but to extend further sounds almost clumsy.  I would not use "get late" because you do not acquire late, you simply were late.  I would use "I was late".

As seen from the dictionary.com definition, "get" or "got" has many connotations and so I would recommend avoiding if possible.  "I got tired" sounds almost clumsy, I would use "after staying up late, I felt tired".

As an additional considerations, married as a "participial adjective" is also described below.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/386160/in-get-married-etc-is-married-a-verb-or-an-adjective/386200

Answer (score 1):

*Get X'ed* can mean

- you actively did something to become X'ed - *I got my car washed at the car wash.*

*or*

- something/someone else did something to you, but you could not or intentionally did not resist it.  *My car got hit when I crossed the intersection.*  *I got 15 dollars from my mom.*

So it can mean "to acquire" or "to receive."